# how to change spacing and scales to a log scale using plot() in R?

Tags: r, plot, scale

I am trying to plot the results from a SMA liner regression using "smatr" package in R. I have been able to create a plot:

```
sma<-sma(data = forewing_R ,formula = y~x*groups,
     method = "SMA", type = "shift", log = "xy")

plot(sma, col = c("Black", "Red", "Blue", "Dark Green"),
 pch= c(5:10), log = "xy")
legend(0.765, 0.84, c("Control", "Low", "Medium", "High"), 
   pch = c(5,7,8,6),  col=c("Black", "Blue", "Dark Green", "Red"))
```

[image]

However, the numbers in the axis are supposed to be log scaled. the end figure should be looking something like this:
[image]

notice how they are similar numbers, but the log scale spacing is different. Unfortunately, I have not been able to figure out how to make these adjustments. it'll be great if anyone can help with this.

Comment: We are missing both your code and data. Poor quality question. You should make an effort to read a)  [edit], b) [MCVE] and c) [help].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log scales, in base plots in R, are simple.

```
x <- y <- 1:10
plot(y~x, log='xy')
```

Two alternate options:

```
plot(y~x, log='x'); plot(y~x, log='y')
```

**EDIT**

The reason why you can't see a log scale on your graph, is because it is too small

```
x_small <- y_small <- seq(0.7,0.8,0.01)
x <- y <- seq(0.1,0.9,0.01)
plot(y_small ~ x_small, log='xy') #domain too small to see effect of log
plot(y ~ x, log='xy') #domain large enough to see effect of log
```

Comment: I already tried that and it gives me the scaling that I have in the picture

Comment: @Maroro92, this is the issue with not providing any code in your original question (see the comment of @42). I know you fixed it after I posted my response to provide the code, but at this point, everybody thought your question had been answered, and we could not see that you had tried adding log='xy'. The reason why is that your range of x and y values is very small, so we cannot see a log scale in such a small range.
NB: Your code now is still not reproducible. If anybody copies and pastes it into a completely empty R session, it won't run. Always check this, you'll receive much better help

Comment: Thank you! I realize my mistake and will try to work on it for future questions